# 5th and 6th order Runge-Kutta methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I want to solve one system of ODE problem with numerical methods. I used RK2, RK3, RK4 and the Adams-Bashforth method. Now I want to solve it with higher-order Runge-Kutta methods. Do you have these tables? And do you know other explicit method to solve this problem?

Comment: Do not go beyond RK4. The results may not be consistent. RK4 is the best...

Comment: http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/mscthesis/cbm-mscthesis.pdf could be of interest.

Comment: http://sce.uhcl.edu/feagin/courses/rk10.pdf

Comment: +1 but the question is quite short for me

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty options, see for instance the [List on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Explicit_methods).

Examples for fifth order explicit schemes include [Runge-Kutta Fehlberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta%E2%80%93Fehlberg_method) and [Dormand-Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormand%E2%80%93Prince_method).

Yet another list can be found on the documentation pages of e.g. [DifferentialEquations.jl](https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/solvers/ode_solve/#Explicit-Runge-Kutta-Methods) or [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/choose-an-ode-solver.html). You can probably find something similar for `SciPy`.